# Summation Notation (Discrete Mathematics)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, notation, summation-method

I am currently studying sequence which I think will lead up to my next topic induction.

My question is if $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k+1}{n+k}= \frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n+1}+\frac{3}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{n+1}{2n}$$

how is this summation notation $$\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k+1}{n+k}$$ equal to this expanded form $\frac{n+1}{2n}$

They give different values so how is it the summation notation of the expanded form ?

EDIT: 
The reason for my question comes from Discrete Algebra and its Application 
[Taken from Discrete Algebra and its Application](http://image.prntscr.com/image/3ccedd6381094e9a94a171955b336f32.png)

Comment: What does $\equiv$ mean here?

Comment: equivalent  or am i using equivalent sign wrongly ? @Henrik

Comment: @Peter havent tried the induction yet still reading sequence but i dont get how the expanded form gives the result of the Summation Form

Comment: @Alec The $\equiv$ sign usually does mean "is equivalent to", but what that means is a matter of context. It isn't clear what you intend by it. Could you explain more?

Comment: @Alec: As you point out, the sum is clearly not equal to $\frac{n+1}{2n}$. Indeed the sum on the left does not have a "closed" form.

Comment: But "equivalent" in what sense? Modulo 2, modulo 3, ...

Comment: @Alec Sorry, I did not notice that the result $\frac{n+1}{2n}$ is wrong.

Comment: @Alec The sums are not equal, as discussed above, and the "equivalent" sign could mean pretty much anything out of context. For what it's worth, the sum in the LHS behaves asymptotically like $n(1+\ln 2)$ when $n\to\infty$ (if you want a proof, it's not too hard); while the RHS converges to a constant, $1/2$.

Comment: @Henrik Hopefully my edit will clarify what i mean by using "equivalent to" if not ill try my best to clarify.

Comment: That just made it even less clear.

Comment: @Alec As Henrik said, this does not help in understand what you mean by equivalent. Rephrasing my comment above: the RHS is bounded, the LHS goes to infinity with $n$. That'll make it hard for them to be equivalent for any meaningful definition of "equivalent."

Comment: @Henrik i added an img of the actuall question to help clarify

Comment: @ClementC. Okay will change the equivalent

Comment: Uh? The image you link never claims anything with "equivalence" as you seem to define it. It just says that $$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k+1}{n+k}= \frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n+1}+\frac{3}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{n+1}{2n}$$ that is all. There is nowhere a claim that the sum is "equivalent" to $\frac{n+1}{2n}$ in any way.

Comment: @Théophile : I am puzzled by your statement that $\text{“}{\equiv}\text{''}$ usually means "is equivalent to".  Sometimes I've seen $A\equiv B$ used to mean $A$ remains equal to $B$ regardless of the values of the variables found in $A$ and $B$, and sometimes I've seen it used to mean $A$ is congruent to $B$ with respect to a modulus, and I think I've seen it used in other senses. "Equivalent" when used when no equivalence relation has been specified or suggested by the context usually means _logically_ equivalent, and that's a relation between two things each of which is true or false.

Comment: @ClementC. Okay i was under the impression that a Summation Notation is alway equal to its Expanded form ( explicitly ) didnt think it could be wrong

Comment: Well, the question is asking to *find* the summation notation; i.e., it's an exercise aimed at rewriting the expanded form into the condensed version. If you find a wrong expression (what you answer as the "summation notation" actually isn't), then surely the two won't be equal.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I was thinking particularly of modular congruence. (I believe that "equivalent modulo $n$" and "congruent modulo $n$" are synonyms). But yes, I could have worded my comment more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a confusion as how you read the question you link. It asks you to *find* the summation notation for
$$
\frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n+1}+\frac{3}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{n+1}{2n} \tag{1}.
$$
$(1)$ is then called *expanded form* of the sum, because... well, it lists all the terms that are summed.

Then, the answer says that the summation notation for the expanded form $(1)$ is
$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k+1}{n+k} \tag{2}
$$
that is, $(2)$ is a shorter, condensed rewriting of $(1)$. That is all that is claimed: $(1)=(2)$, i.e. the two are equal:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k+1}{n+k}= \frac{1}{n}+\frac{2}{n+1}+\frac{3}{n+2}+\cdots+\frac{n+1}{2n}.
$$
Nothing more.